# Using CiviCRM + S3 for ~10M contacts

Tags: contacts, database, deployment, architecture, aws

We're planning to use CiviCRM for a large number of voters (~10M voters). Most of these voters will never be contacted and so we don't need all of them in CiviCRM. We'd like to store these contacts in AWS S3 and use a querying service like AWS Athena. We query the data in S3 and only upload the filtered list of contacts. We will use the Athena API and the CSV Import API to fetch data from S3 and import to CiviCRM. My questions are the following:

1. Any architectural suggestions on making this work?
2. Any alternative approach to make this work?
3. What happens when too may contacts are uploaded into CiviCRM? Any suggestions on splitting them into multiple databases when the size grows?

Comment: for others. 3/ relates also to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37402/different-schema-database-in-multisite