# Different Schema / Database in Multisite

Tags: contacts, database, multisite, datatables

We're planning to use CiviCRM for a large number of voters (~10M voters).

This questions is related to the one [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37401/using-civicrm-s3-for-10m-contacts).

We were wondering if it's possible to split these 10M voters into different schemas. We want to keep one large database server instead of multiple smaller ones. We could divide the contacts based on geographies and store each of them in a separate site. Each site has its own schema. That way when we're filtering contacts on one site, it doesn't have to scan the entire contact database.

My question is - can we specify the scehma using a prefix? Or use some other configuration to point to a particular schema for an installation?

Comment: I'm a little confused where you say you want one large database, but then say each site has its own schema. If you mean "one large webserver" with multiple databases, then drupal multisite might be what you want - so only one set of code files, but a separate database for each virtual host: https://www.drupal.org/docs/multisite-drupal

Comment: Gufran - hi - can you explain what the goal is overall? To have to only set up custom data, activity types, etc etc in only one system but to have users perceive they are using different databases to each other. asking as we did a bunch of work to make is to eg custom fields created on the 'master' got pushed out to the 'child' databases